# Can the Google maps V2 Webservice still be used after March 8, 2013

Tags: google-maps, google-geocoding-api

We are still using the Google maps V2 webservice because we are not yet finished with the migration of the V2 webservice to the V3.
Will it still be possbible to use the V2 webservice after March 8 or will it not working at all anymore after this date?

Is there some work around possible until we have finished the migration to V3.

Comment: I think you should elaborate your question with the information about what platform you are talking about and assign more tags to make it reader friendly.

Answer (score 3):

See the documentation [Note: The Google Maps Geocoding API Version 2 has been officially deprecated as of March 8, 2010. The V2 API will continue to work until Mar 8, 2013. We encourage you to migrate your code to the new Geocoding API. Please refer to the upgrade guide for information on how to migrate to the v3 API.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/v2/index)

It doesn't say it will stop working on March 8th, 2013, but it could, and it will no longer be supported, so if something breaks, they are under no obligation to fix it.  It has been deprecated for almost 3 years, you are strongly encouraged to migrate before March 8th.

Answer (score 0):

Note: The Google Maps JavaScript API Version 2 has been officially deprecated as of May 19, 2010. The V2 API will continue to work until May 19, 2013.

[src](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/)

Answer (score 0):

Depreciation of Version 2 of the Google Maps API has now been [extended through November 19, 2013](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/). After that, v2 applications may continue to work as long as they are "simple maps" since the V3 API will be delivered through a wrapper on the Google side of things. Google did not define what a "simple map" is.